# jQuery Validate, validate select:visible

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-validate

I'm working on a project with jQuery Validate (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), where some `selects` are displayed if you click on some `checkboxes`.

The checkboxes group is required, but I only want to make the visible `SELECT` required.

I tried to `addClass("required")` when I show the `SELECT`, but that didn't work.

I've searched the entire web, or that how it feels that it, but I can't find any solution.

Is it possible to validate only the visible `SELECTs` or how should I do this?

Thank you in advance.

*** UPDATE ***
Please see this my example: http://jsfiddle.net/mtLZG/17/

Comment: Are you using a plug-in for this, which one? Have you tried simply `$('input:visible:text').addClass('required')`? Or was it something other part that didn't work?

Comment: You could try removing the "hidden" ones from the page with Jquery .remove (http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
Not sure if this will work for you, which is why I've commented, instead of adding it as an answer.

Do you have a URL that is publicly accessible for your project?

Comment: show the markup and the code you have so far so we can help

Comment: This is how I've made it so far: http://jsfiddle.net/mtLZG/17/

Answer (score 1):

with this code you are okay:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //Shows the sub-options, if checkboxes are selected per default $('input:checked').parent().addClass("visible");

$(':checkbox').live("change", function(){
    //Show the suboption
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("visible");
    //Add required-class to the Select
    $(this).parent().children("select").toggleClass("required");  
    //I tried to validate the form again, after the above class was added
    $('form').validate();      
});

//Validate
$('form').validate();
});
```

i changed a bit of your markup so that it works a little better. Look at the fiddle if it works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/mtLZG/18/

Comment: Your jsFiddle setup is potentially confusing... which of the _three_ included instances of the Validate plugin are required for your demo?  1.  in the HTML pane, 2. in the Resources panel, 3. in the JavaScript pane.

Comment: There is no need to repeatedly call `.validate()`.  It's for the one-time initialization of the plugin.  There are other built-in events and methods that negate any need to have to re-initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the validation code as

```
$('form').validate({
   ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

It should handle things just fine as far as ignoring hidden selects.  Of course, there are other potential issues with select validation too.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older question, but I believe this answer is worthwhile to the reader since jQuery Validate ([since plugin version 1.9.0](http://bassistance.de/2011/10/07/release-validation-plugin-1-9-0/)) now ignores hidden fields *by default*.

This is mostly the OP's jQuery with all the unnecessary lines removed, and `.live()` updated to the more modern [jQuery `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('input:checked').parent().addClass("visible");

    $(':checkbox').on("change", function () {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("visible");
    });

    // Initialize Validate plugin; .validate() called ONCE
    $('form').validate({
        ignore: ":hidden"  // only use this option for plugin version below 1.9.0
    });

});
```

In order for this to work, the following changes also need to be applied to your HTML:

1)  `select` element needs a `name` attribute or the Validate plugin will ignore it.

2)  `select` element needs `class='required'` to assign the rule.  (This is now automatically  ignored whenever the element is hidden.)

3)  First `option` needs a `value=""` attribute to tell the plugin that the first item is not a valid option.

```
<select class="required" name="suboption1">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Select an option</option>
    <option>Sub-Option 1</option>
    ...
</select>
```

**Working Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/ZLXuU/

**General Notes:**

1)  [Use `.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) to *initialize* the plugin *ONCE* on DOM ready.

2)  There is never a need to call `.validate()` again since it only re-initializes the plugin.  [Use `.valid()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid) to *test* the form's validity and trigger any error messages.

3)  `ignore: ":hidden"` is now a *default* option for Validate version 1.9.0+